# Django Heroku - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_social_share'

Tags: django, heroku

My django site works fine locally but on Heroku has "Application Error" Page .
but it exists in settings.py file

Thanks in advance
so i typed
`heroku logs --tail`

My heroku log :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added social_share manually in **pipfile**
`[packages] django-social-share = "==2.2.1"`
because it didn't added automatically ..
then in terminal
**pipenv lock**
and finally
pushed latest changes and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Inside heroku terminal do `pip install django-social-share`
or include `django-social-share` in your `requirementes.txt` file.